# loop through the data in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having difficult loop through the data in PDO and print the data as long as there it has more data for a specific user. I create a function which performs the select. Here is the code that contain the select function, http://pastebin.com/GiAyCBys. I am trying to use that function in cartexe.php using the following code,

```
    while($row = select($conn, 'user', 'cart', $user,':user','*'))
   {    
       echo 'Hello';
    }
```

but I got stuck in an infinite loop. I am grateful for any help I can get.

Comment: I still get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: This might help you as it poses a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601534/infinite-php-while-loop

Comment: I can definitely do while using mysqli or mysql query without any difficult. This is a bit different because I am using PDO and I am also calling function.

Comment: Then I think your only recourse is to set a condition to allow you to exit the loop or do not use a while loop.

Comment: I think this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488364/how-to-properly-use-while-loop-in-pdo-fetchall

Comment: Then answer your own question and show us how you came to your conclusion. Might help out another poor soul with the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to change `select` to return all rows , since `fetch()` only return a single row at the time.

**Option 1:**

```
$result = array();
while($row = $smtp->fetch(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC)){    
  $result[]=$row;
}             
return $result;
```

**option 2:**

```
$result = $smtp->fetchAll(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC);
return $result;
```

use your function like this

```
$rows = select($conn, 'user', 'cart', $user,':user','*');
foreach($rows as $row){
 //do something with $row
}
```

Comment: The fetch and for each was how I solved the problem like hours ago. I really appreciate the inputs as they were what gave me a better insight on approaching, tackled and corrected the problem.